# API sandbox for ISO 8583 APIs

Tags: iso, iso8583

I'm currently looking for ISO 8583 APIs Sandboxes. There seems to be a lot of resources for working with JSON/XML data exchange formats. But, I don't see much resources for working with ISO 8583 data.

I tried exploring https://community.developer.visa.com/t5/Sandbox-Test-Data/merchantsearch-v1-search-API-and-ISO-8583-message-mapping/td-p/15479, but the sandbox mentioned there does not work. Any links provided would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

these online coders/de-coders helped me when I worked with it

https://neapay.com/online-tools/bitmap-fields-decoder.html

https://neapay.com/online-tools/bitmap-fields-decoder.html

https://paymentcardtools.com/iso-8583-bitmap

https://codebeautify.org/hex-string-converter